# Content positioning using the Full Width Image Carousel of Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

here is my question:

- How I am able to adjust the position of my content (like text, etc.) inside of the of slider responsively!
- Position of the text could be anywhere inside of the Div Slider, but as example: 25% left and 50% height inside the dimensions of the Image Div Slider

Thank's a lot!

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
 
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption slide_one_position">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to position it? It currently isn't very clear what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reply. Just anywhere inside of the Slider Div. Like most of the times, I will insert 1-3 paragraphs on the left side and pretty centred. Thank ya.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positioning and styling of Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Image Captions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887484/positioning-and-styling-of-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-image-captions)

Comment: I use vw font sizes and position absolutely with percentages.  I makes for a fluid fully responsive banner.  Don't forget media queries for font sizes past you max width of the viewport window.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 18px;
}

img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You can do this to center text inside the image and to be responsive
In your case `<h3 class="center">Some text</h3>`

Double check if carousel-caption and item classes have `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set the image like you do here.

there is a simple way then what are you write here.
you can use something like this:

```
/* html */
<img class="yourClass" src="imgSrc" />

// css
IMG.yourClass{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

that easier way to center img with css3.